# App engine build aborts on error Environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am trying to deploy a django 1.6 project to google app engine using their push to deploy tutorial https://cloud.google.com/tools/repo/push-to-deploy-quickstart. the project works perfectly fine locally but when I push the project, app engine seems to fall back to django 0.96 when a django model is imported as you can see in the error below. why does this happen?

```
======================================================================
    ERROR: Failure: EnvironmentError (Environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.)
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/loader.py", line 414, in loadTestsFromName
        addr.filename, addr.module)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
        return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
        mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
      File "/var/jenkins/workspace/mango_app/apps/merchant/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from gateways import *
      File "/var/jenkins/workspace/mango_app/apps/merchant/gateways/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from plugnpay import PlugnPay
      File "/var/jenkins/workspace/mango_app/apps/merchant/gateways/plugnpay.py", line 5, in <module>
        from apps.merchant.exceptions import MissingDataError
      File "/var/jenkins/workspace/mango_app/apps/merchant/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from gateways import *
      File "/var/jenkins/workspace/mango_app/apps/merchant/gateways/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from plugnpay import PlugnPay
      File "/var/jenkins/workspace/mango_app/apps/merchant/gateways/plugnpay.py", line 6, in <module>
        from apps.merchant.lib.api import PostGateway
      File "/var/jenkins/workspace/mango_app/apps/merchant/lib/api.py", line 6, in <module>
        from apps.merchant.gateways.core import Gateway
      File "/var/jenkins/workspace/mango_app/apps/merchant/gateways/core.py", line 7, in <module>
        from apps.merchant.gateways.models import PlugnpayResponseModel
      File "/var/jenkins/workspace/mango_app/apps/merchant/gateways/models.py", line 1, in <module>
        from django.db import models
      File "/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/django-0.96/django/db/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
        if not settings.DATABASE_ENGINE:
      File "/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/django-0.96/django/conf/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
        self._import_settings()
      File "/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/django-0.96/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in _import_settings
        raise EnvironmentError, "Environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE
    EnvironmentError: Environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

app.yaml

```
application: instance-id
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

env_variables:
  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: 'myproject.settings'

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: myproject.wsgi.application
```

wsgi.py

```
import sys


sys.path.insert(0,'./Lib/site-packages')
sys.path.insert(1,'./apps')

import os


#Delete current django version in production
for key in [key for key in sys.modules if key.startswith('django')]:
  del sys.modules[key]


from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
_application = get_wsgi_application()


def application(environ, start_response):
    try:
        os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'
    except Exception:
        pass

    return _application(environ, start_response)
```

I have also tried to place this line of code inside appengine_config.py :

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mango.settings'
```

directory structure

```
C:.
│   .gitignore
│   app.yaml
│   appengine_config.py
│   manage.py
│   requirements.txt
│   __init__.py
├───apps
├───lib
│   __init__.py
├───myproject
│   app.py
│   settings.py
│   urls.py
│   views.py
│   wsgi.py
│   __init__.py
```

Answer (score 0):

App Engine does not include Django 1.6.  You will need to add it to your project and upload it.  Or, you can use Django 1.5 with GAE, by adding this you your app.yaml:

```
libraries:
- name: django
  version: "1.5"
```

Otherwise, you are stuck using a very old version (0.96) which was the GAE default several years ago.  If you are going to use your own django, and not the 1.5 included with GAE, I recommend using django-nonrel.

By doing either of the above, you can eliminate the deletion of django in production (in wsgi.py), which is most likely causing your error.